# DeepLearning4J NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, lucene, neural-network, deep-learning, word2vec

I'm new to neural networks and NLP. I've found this library: DeepLearning4J. I'm trying to get it to work but whenever I execute this instruction:

```
Collection<String> similar = vec.wordsNearest("word_to_search", 10);
```

If the word I'm searching is mapped into the network I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XERBLA: Error on argument 6 (LDA) in SGEMV
at org.jblas.NativeBlas.sgemv(Native Method)
at org.nd4j.linalg.jblas.blas.JblasLevel2.sgemv(JblasLevel2.java:25)
at org.nd4j.linalg.api.blas.impl.BaseLevel2.gemv(BaseLevel2.java:53)
at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.mmuli(BaseNDArray.java:2569)
at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.mmul(BaseNDArray.java:2377)
at org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.wordvectors.WordVectorsImpl.wordsNearest(WordVectorsImpl.java:290)
at org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.wordvectors.WordVectorsImpl.wordsNearest(WordVectorsImpl.java:337)
at word2vec.Word2VecTest.main(Word2VecTest.java:74)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray.mean(I)Lorg/nd4j/linalg/api/ndarray/INDArray;
at org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.wordvectors.WordVectorsImpl.wordsNearest(WordVectorsImpl.java:283)
at word2vec.Word2VecTest.main(Word2VecTest.java:89)
```

I know that the NoSuchMethodError may be due to libraries different versions. In this specific case, this is probably caused by nd4j. I've checked the versions lots of time and this is what I'm importing at the moment:

- akka-actor_2.11-2.4-M3.jar
- akka-cluster_2.11-2.4-M3.jar
- akka-remote_2.11-2.4-M3.jar
- akka-slf4j_2.11-2.4-M3.jar
- byte-buddy-0.6.15.jar
- config-1.3.0.jar
- deeplearning4j-core-0.0.3.3.4.alpha2.jar
- deeplearning4j-nlp-0.0.3.3.4.alpha2.jar
- deeplearning4j-scaleout-akka-0.0.3.3.4.alpha2.jar
- deeplearning4j-ui-0.0.3.3.4.alpha2.jar
- javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar
- jblas-1.2.4.jar
- jcublas-6.5.jar
- lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.3.jar
- lucene-core-4.10.3.jar
- nd4j-api-0.4-rc3.4.jar
- nd4j-bytebuddy-0.4-rc3.4.jar
- nd4j-jblas-0.4-rc3.4.jar
- nd4j-jcublas-common-0.4-rc3.4.jar
- netty-3.10.4.Final.jar
- protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar
- reflections-0.9.10.jar
- scala-library-2.12.0-M2.jar
- selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar

Can someone explain to me the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you that DeepLearning4J tried to call the method `INDArray INDArray.mean(int value)` but this method was not found.

Looking at [nd4j 0.4-rc3.4 source code](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j/blob/nd4j-0.4-rc3.4/nd4j-api/src/main/java/org/nd4j/linalg/api/ndarray/INDArray.java#L1410), you can see that the `mean` method actually takes a vararg `int...` as input. Since this is not `int`, the error is thrown.

This change was made by [this commit](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j/commit/f139952229efad88a1e0e3f5ba6f8d2fc0099ff6#diff-97e0fa927feddd349589443d487cd5a0L1280) when `nd4j` bumped version from `0.0.3.5.5.5` to `0.4-rc0`.

As a result, you need to downgrade `nd4j` to version `0.0.3.5.5.5`. With this downgrade, you will not have any more incompatibility since this is the actual version that DeepLearning4J is depending on. You can see that in the Maven dependencies of [`deeplearning4j-core-0.0.3.3.4.alpha2`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core/0.0.3.3.4.alpha2).

Comment: This was exactly the problem. After downgrading I had to fix some other dependencies but now is working fine. Funny enough I had that version originally and I don't remember why I've upgraded. I spent countless hours trying to fix it and I probably would have never figured that out without your help. Thank you very much.